# rpm postinstall for different versions of distribution

Tags: rpm, rhel, rpm-spec

I am building a `rpm` which should be usable for both RHEL 6 and 7.

I am able to find and install correct files based on `0%{?rhel}`.

But is it possible to make the postinstall script work that way during installation. If i use the `0%{?rhel}` in postinstall, the corresponding scripts are made part of rpm during build time.

Is it possible to do distribution based scripts during installation time in postinstall section?

Answer (score 1):

**NO** I would not recommend that. `rpmbuild` will automatically determine your dependencies, some things will just be different. I would recommend to build your `rpm` on its target os to avoid trouble.

**YES** you can make an rpm that will work both on rhel 6 and 7. But it won't be so clean, and you won't be able to use rpm macros, because those are evaluated during build. You could however:

```
%post
. /etc/os-release
if [ ${VERSION_ID%%.*} -eq 7 ] && [ $ID == rhel ]
then
    echo "on rhel 7"
else
    echo "on $ID $VERSION_ID"
fi
```

Comment: @Fazlin Did this anwser solve your problem? If so please accept this answer.